# Remove digits after decimal notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Basically all over the document I have values like

2014-01-23 15:09:31.879958

I want to remove the last 6 digits and the . using find and replace. I've gotten

```
(\d{6})
```

To find the 6 digits but I also need it to find the . so I can replace it with nothing

Comment: `\.` = a dot in regex. You need to escape it as `.` has special meaning (any character). Hence `\.(\d{6})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `\.\d{6}` - the `\.` escapes the dot.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should be able to simply add a period to your find/replace.

As a test, I copied your example multiple times in a document. I then attempted to Find the following: `\.(\d{6})` and replace with a blank

Give that a try and see if that works for you.

Cheers,

Edited to add the slash that I apparently didn't type. Silly.